# I added Lombok, but when I run it, get a getter / setter error

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

I am using Eclipse on Window. When running the program, an error occurred

```
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/add.html]").
 Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "add" - line 10, col 40).
Invalid property 'id' of bean class [com.example.demo.models.Book]: Bean property 'id' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Class Entity

```
@Table(name = "book")
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Book implements Serializable{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String image;
    
}
```

Class Controller

```
@Controller
public class BookController {
    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String add(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("book", new Book());
        return "add";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String save(ModelMap model, Book book) {
        bookService.save(book);
        model.addAttribute(book);
        return list(model);
    }
        @GetMapping("/list")
    public String list(ModelMap model) {
        List<Book> list = (List<Book>) bookService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("books", list);
        return "list";
    }
}
```

Class Template

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert Book</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${book}" method="post">
        <div th:if="${id == null}">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Id" th:field="*{id}" /><br />
        </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" th:field="*{name}" /><br /> <input
            type="text" th:field="*{image}" placeholder="Image" /><br /> <input
            type="submit" value="Confirm"> <a th:href="@{/list}">List</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I added and installed Lombok and it didn't get any error but getter / setter error when running the program, so try to replace it manually and run successfully. I think it was Lombok's fault, but nothing was found.
.

Comment: Are you sure that you imported both Getter and Setter interfaces from lombok package? Would you like to try Data annotation instead? Also, did you miss Column annotation on the Id attribute?

Answer (score 0):

The error is on the code below:

```
    <div th:if="${id == null}">
```

You can fix that by replacing it with:

```
    <div th:if="${book.id == null}">
```

You might be mislead by the error, but it is not related with `Lombok`.